# Change the value in select list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

Good day,

I am currently creating a select list like so:

```
  return new SelectList(db.RadioNetworks
                          .OrderBy(x => x.RepeaterName), 
                          "NetworkIdentifier", "RepeaterName");
```

Which enables me to populate a dropdown list with the "RepeaterName"

How can i change this to keept he same key value, but I want a compound data field.

so like

```
  return new SelectList(db.RadioNetworks
                          .OrderBy(x => x.RepeaterName), 
                          "NetworkIdentifier", "RepeaterName"+" - " + "startCode");
```

how can I do this?

even if I have to loop through a list of Radio Networks and build the select list manually.

Comment: What framework are you using? Are you using bindings? Do the bindings need to be two-way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that startCode is a property of your radionetwork object, so you can create a collection of new objects with the combined info, then populate the SelectList:

```
return new SelectList(db.RadioNetworks.OrderBy(x => x.RepeaterName)
                        .Select(x => new 
                        {
                            NetworkIdentifier = x.NetworkIdentifier,
                            Name = x.RepeaterName + " - " + x.startCode
                        }),
                     "NetworkIdentifier",
                     "Name");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a Wrapper, something along these lines:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    RadioNetwork m_r;
    public Wrapper(RadioNetwork r) { m_r=r; }
    public object NetworkIdentifier { get { return m_r.NetworkIdentifier; }}
    public string Text { get { return m_r.RepeaterName.ToString()+"-"+m_r.startCode; }}
}

...
return new SelectList(db.RadioNetworks.OrderBy(x => x.RepeaterName).Select(x=>new Wrapper(x)), "NetworkIdentifier", "Text");
```

Edit: Manji beat me to it. And his version with an anonymous class is easier on the eyes.